# How to summarise a dataframe in R with different function for different column?

Tags: r, group-by

In the following dataframe, how do I summarise the table group by Ticker, and for each Ticker, use the max function for TradeDate, the sum function for SharesBought, max for HighestPxPaid, and min for LowestPxPaid?  Thanks!

[click here for dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOc2B.png)

Comment: Use `data.table` or `dplyr`. For instance, with `data.table` something like `setDT(df)[,list(max(TradeDate),sum(SharesBought),...),by=Ticker]` should work (`df` is your `data.frame`).

Comment: I tried:  
setDT(df)[,list(max(TradeDate),sum(SharesBought),max(HighestPxPaid),min(LowestPxPaid)),by=Ticker]

and it returned "Error in gmax(TradeDate) : max is not meaningful for factors."  I have tried converting it to as.character as well as as.numeric but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `dplyr` package. You can try the following code: if df is your dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
summarised_df <- group_by(df, Ticker) %>%
                 summarise(
                           max(tradeDate), 
                           sum(SharesBought), 
                           max(HighestPxPaid), 
                           min(LowestPxPaid)
                 )
```

Comment: Don't forget to indicate that the issue is solved ;)

Comment: I just clicked the green tick, that's what I need to do to indicate this is solved?

Comment: Yes, that's it!